# Multi-row writing of HEX-BIN conversion in a column with openpyxl (python)

Tags: python, excel, binary, hex, openpyxl

My goal is to convert the cell's value (for each row in a certain range in column E) from HEX to BIN and write the BIN in column N for each row. There is no problem with the conversion itself as well as writing the BIN value to a certain cell. But I have issues with the iteration through the rows. Just to clarify: I want the HEX code in E1 printed in BIN code in N1, the value in E2 being printed in N2, and so on

```
A  B  C D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N
           90                         ‭10010000‬
           8A                         ‭10001010‬
           ..                         ....
```

Here is my code:

```
theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('T013.xlsx')
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames 
print("All sheet names {} " .format(theFile.sheetnames)) 
sheet = theFile.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1210,values_only = True): 
    for cell in sheet["E"]: 
        if cell.value is None:
            print("Blank")
        else: 
            inputHEX = str(cell.value) 
            res = "{0:08b}".format(int(inputHEX,16))
            print(res)
            for x in sheet["N1:N1210"]:
                sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value = str(res) #same error as with res without str 
theFile.save("C:\\Users\\...\\Adapted_T013.xlsx")
```

The error that I get is:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop\Practical Part\CAN Python>python ExcelDecode.py
All sheet names ['T013']
Blank
11100001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExcelDecode.py", line 42, in <module>
    sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value = res
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.0.3-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 235, in cell
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`
```

I tried using a tuple converting function but that did not change the outcome.

It would be great if you could show me a way to overcome this error. Thank you!

Comment: Please include the complete traceback

Comment: @CharlieClark: Thank you for the remark! I have included the traceback. Does that help to understand the issue?

Comment: @Nezuko ***`TypeError: '<'`***: Your error is `x` in , `.cell(row=x`,. `x` is a `tuple` of `values` but `row=` expects a `int`. Remove your complete `for x in...` and do `.cell(row=cell.row, column=<index of Column N>)`

Comment: @stovfl: Thank you very much for the explanation and the tip! I was able to get what I wanted. So so glad :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Implementation:**

```
theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('T013.xlsx')
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames 
print("All sheet names {} " .format(theFile.sheetnames)) 
sheet = theFile.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1210,values_only = True): 
    for cell in sheet["E"]:
        if cell.value is not None:
            inputHEX = str(cell.value)
            res = "{0:08b}".format(int(inputHEX,16))
            sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=14).value = res
    break
theFile.save("C:\\Users\\..\\Adapted_T013.xlsx")
```